# How to enable thumbnail previews in Nautilus in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, nautilus, thumbnails

I want to use Nautilus as default file manager instead of Thunar but it does not generate thumbnails for new media files that I add. How do I enable this behaviour?

Also how do I access preferences/settings for Nautilus? I cannot find the menu bar anywhere.

Comment: Use your terminal for the command: 'gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size #'. Change # with the pixel size you want (like 24/36/48/whatever)

Comment: @DKBose I like Xubuntu as a DE, just don't want Thunar since it's buggy and doesn't have the features I want. Nautilus works great on Xubuntu except it doesn't generate thumbnails for new files.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee It didn't do anything. Nautilus is not generating thumbnails so I don't understand how changing the icon size will help.

Comment: Did you try the command? Try once.

Comment: @ArijitChatterjee I did.